# Are there any non-deprecated Eclipse PDE plugin templates?

Tags: eclipse, templates, eclipse-plugin, deprecated, eclipse-pde

I'm learning how to develop plugins for eclipse, and I'm trying to add a menu item to a context menu. That sounds simple enough, and in the "New Plugin Project" wizard, several templates are given, one of which creates a new item in the context menu.

The problem is Eclpse's own templates contain deprecated code. How can I learn how to develop proper code if even the provided templates use deprecated structures? Are there any templates out there which use modern structures like `MenuContributions` instead of deprecated structures like `ActionSet` and `PopupMenus`?

For the record, I am using the latest version of Eclipse SDK, Indigo 4.2.1.

Comment: This is a tutorial that may help: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html

Comment: I don't require RCP for my plugin. I'm not sure if this tutorial is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no templates for the command/menu API.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194669

A good tutorial on commands is:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html

Comment: I'm disappointed in the lack of templates, but that bug report seems to answer my question. I had some trouble with the vogella tutorial, but I found this one to be helpful: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-3.3menu/